# OrientDb querying with lucene engine on linked class

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I use OrientDb 2.1.13.

I have the following database structure

```
Area extends V          
---------------------------
Field     Type
---------------------------
names     LinkMap to AreaName



AreaName extends V
---------------------------
Field     Type
---------------------------
language  String
name      String   (with a Lucene Index on this field)
```

And I have the following values

```
Area
------------------------------
@rid         names
------------------------------
#12:6025     {"en":"#13:6025"}


AreaName
------------------------------
@rid         language      name
------------------------------
#12:6025     en            Africa
```

I tried to extract data from Area using the following query, but nothing is extracted.

```
1) select from Area where names.en.name lucene 'Africa*'
```

Instead using the following query I can extract data (using = instead of LUCENE)

```
2) select from Area where names.en.name = 'Africa'
```

and also using this query (so the lucene engine works well if used directly):

```
3) select from Area where names.en in 
   (select from AreaName where name lucene 'Africa*')
```

I would like to know which is the right way to query a linked class with a field indexed with lucene. My questions are:

Is a bug that the query 1) doesn't work?

It is necessary to use a different syntax?

Or the only way is to use a subquery, like in 3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query

```
select from Area where names.en.name lucene 'Africa*'
```

the target class is Area and therefore are searched the indexes on the class Area and not on AreaName

With this query

```
select from Area where names.en.name = 'Africa'
```

you can extract data but you don't use the index

With this query you use the index on the field name

```
select from Area where names.en in 
   (select from AreaName where name lucene 'Africa*')
```

I think that you must use the subquery like in 3.

Comment: This is valid only for LUCENE or for any kind of index?

Comment: It's valid for any kind of index